# Print shape of numbers using arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I want to print the shape of numbers using 2D arrays. What I am saying is just like this. Think I want print num 2.

```
111111
    11
111111
11
111111
```

I already tried, starting like this, but I cant build it further.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

int Num[5][6]=  {{111111},
                {000011},
                {111111},
                {110000},
                {111111}};
 int i,j;
 for(i=0;i<6;i++){
     for(j=0;j<7;j++){
          printf("%d",Num[i][j]); 
     }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Instead of spaces i have included "0" in my code.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What code have you tried?

Comment: java or c ....?

Comment: That is not even an half-hearted attempt, sorry.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: if it is C, it would be better

Comment: @roch.p: Yeah, because if it was Java it wouldn't compile. :)

Comment: You already have an example of number 2 - do the same for the rest numbers, what the *actual* problem?

Comment: `int var=000011;` is nothing more than a number in base 8 (i.e `int var=011`). Use char array better.

Comment: In Java, simply write each number as a string literal: `String two = "111111\n" + "    11\n" + ...` (except write each part on separate lines, so it looks like what you're trying to print).

Comment: @Yuriy Ivaskevych What want is print Num 2. It is an example what was just written, not from any code..

Comment: BTW: array indexes start at 0 not at 1.

Comment: @MichaelWalz :  I tried like that also... but it printed nothing

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: @roch.p your solution is not so far from the truth, look at the answer below..

Comment: I have added some changes in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  int Num[5][6] =
  {
    { 1,1,1,1,1,1 },
    { 0,0,0,0,1,1 },
    { 1,1,1,1,1,1 },
    { 1,1,1,1,0,0 },
    { 1,1,1,1,1,1 } 
  };

  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i<5; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j<6; j++) {
      if (Num[i][j] == 1)
        printf("1");
      else
        printf(" ");
    }

    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Disclaimer: there is still room for improvement. The proposed solution is as close as possible to the original code.

Comment: What is wrong with my code? Without using that headers can't i print that. I'm new for coding.. :)

Comment: @roch.p You need the stdio.h header, read your C text book. What's wrong with your code: just compare yours to mine, it's very similar.

Comment: @roch.p Actually I'm not quite sure what you meant my _"that headers"_ in your comment. Please elaborate.

Comment: I meant headers for   #include <stdio.h>,  #include <stdlib.h>,   #include <string.h> that you  have created before. It's appreciate for the time  you have given for me. :)

Comment: @roch.p only `#include <stdio.h>` is required.